# facebook login in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

i am creating a web project and i want to get login with facebook but i have this annoying error please help me!
this is my routes

```
 Route::get('auth/facebook','AuthController@redirectToProvider');
 Route::get('auth/facebook/callback','AuthController@handleProviderCallback');
```

this is my controller

```
public function redirectToProvider()
{
    return Socialite::driver('facebook')->redirect();}


public function handleProviderCallback(){
$user = Socialite::driver('facebook')->user();
$data = ['name'=>$user->name, 'email'=>$user->email, 'password'=>$user->token];
$userDB = User::where('email', $user->email)->first();
if(!is_null($userDB)){
  Auth::login($userDB);
}

else{
  User::create([
    'name' => $data['name'],
    'email' => $data['email'],
    'password' => $data['token'],
    ]);
  Auth::login($userDB);}return redirect('/');
}
```

and thi is th service.php
`'facebook' => 
                [
        'client_id' => '1005472786205748',
        'client_secret' => '75d15a7e24c7d61ddecd25a490baeaaf',
        'redirect' => 'http://localhost/PFE/public/auth/facebook',
 ],`

when i click on the boutton of login with facebook it redirect me to facebook.com i enter my adress mail and password but it tell me this :La page www.facebook.com ne fonctionne pas

www.facebook.com vous a redirigé à de trop nombreuses reprises.

Comment: @akshaykhale they are using Socialite already...

Answer (score 0):

Change your `'redirect'` field value to your callback route.

```
'redirect' => 'http://localhost/PFE/public/auth/facebook/callback',
```

This way, you handle the response instead of redirecting to the same route.